# Is there a way to know if a $http request timed out?

Tags: angularjs, http

It seems the status code is 404 for both timed out requests and for `Not found`.

What is the best way to check if the request failed because of a spotty connection (and eventually retry the request) in angular?

Comment: 404 is a server-side response. "resource not found". A network timeout on your client-side code cannot produce a 404. Your request never gets a response to figure out whether the requested resource exists or not. unreachable != not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get a 404 for timeouts.

Just ran this code

```
$http({ method: "GET", url: "http://localhost:4789/foo", timeout: 5000})
    .then(
    function () {
        console.log("all OK");
    },
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

against a URL that busy waits. After 5 seconds, the failure callback of the `$http` promise fires with response:

```
Object {data: null, status: 0, headers: function, config: Object}
```

The status is 0, not 404. Chrome's Network tab shows the request as "(cancelled)".

Comment: Looks like I noobed this one. I obviously tested against non existing resources, but against a valid server. Damn brain.

Comment: *chuckle* How you disambiguate between timeouts and other stuff is beyond me, though I guess status 0 just means "client screwed up" and leaves you to figure out why.